# Append line to specific file extension in C

Tags: c, append

So I have been trying to make a tool which creates text inside files with a specific extension, but ran into an issue and wonder how I can fix it.

Here is the code:

```c
if (d) {
    while (((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)) { // if directory exists
        ext = strchr(dir->d_name, '.'); // const char
        entry_file = fopen(dir->d_name, "a");
        if (strcat(dir->d_name, ".lua")) { // if the file's extension is lua, then apply the changes.
            //fopen(dir->d_name, "r");
            printf(dir->d_name);
            fprintf(entry_file, "filename = ", sentence);
            fclose(entry_file);
        }
    }
    closedir(d); // close directory
}
```

Comment: `strcat` is not `strcmp`. Also indent your code, and it's odd that you `fopen` the file before checking extension. I would open _after_ checking the extension. Never do `printf(dir->d_name);` - it's a security problem, it's `printf("%s", stuff);` `= ", sentence);` it's `%s", sentence)`. Enable compiler warnings (with gcc `-Wall -Wextra` also use `-fsanitize=undefined,addrress`) and fix them all.

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: @KamilCuk did all of the changes, but still does not solve the problem.

Comment: ...Nor have you described the problem.  (_ran into an issue_ does not describe the issue, only indicated that you encountered one.)  And, in comments:  _"still does not solve the problem."_   What problem?

Comment: `if (strcmp(ext, ".lua") == 0)`

Comment: You open the file before checking the filename. Then if the extension doesn't match, you never close it.

Comment: i've placed `fclose` after the lua extension check and changed it with what you've given, but the program affects and returns nothing.

Comment: `fprintf(entry_file, "filename = %s", sentence);` not `fprintf(entry_file, "filename = ", sentence);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not inserting the variable `sentence` into the file. You need the `%s` to tell fprintf to actually include the next argument into the string you're writing to the file.

```
file = fopen(file_name, "a");
fprintf(file, "%s", text_to_append);
fclose(file);
```

As noted in the comments, you need to change your printf to use the format specifier as well. Your code should look something like this after those changes.

```
if (d) {
    while (((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)) {
        ext = strchr(dir->d_name, '.');
        if ((ext != NULL) && (strcmp(ext, ".lua") == 0)) {
            printf("%s", dir->d_name);
            entry_file = fopen(dir->d_name, "a");
            fprintf(entry_file, "filename = %s", sentence);
            fclose(entry_file);
        }
    }
    closedir(d);
}
```

See [format string specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string#Format_string_specifications) for more information about different format specifiers.

Comment: are there changes i shall do if i replace `strcat` with `strcmp` ?

Comment: For your `if`, you want: `if ((ext != NULL) && (strcmp(ext, ".lua") == 0))` to only open files with the `.lua` extension.

Comment: worked as intended! thank you!